# How does Bitcoin Gold difficulty adjustment work?

Tags: bitcoin-gold, difficulty-retargetting

Bitcoin Gold claimed to have per-block difficulty adjustment, how does it work? I find this https://github.com/BTCGPU/BTCGPU/pull/151, but still don't understand how it work by change some parameters.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a simple moving average with a window of 30 blocks:

```
next_D = sum(past 30 D) / sum(past 30 solvetimes) * 600
```

This isn't exactly what it's doing, but it's darn close.

Comment: Thank you. Is this fomula calculated every blocks? And why is 600?

Comment: Time is calculated in terms of millisecond i believe